Smart Wallet on FVM
Is there any possibility that I can deploy a gnosis-safe smart wallet on the FVM network and use that contract as the owner of my protocol contracts to decentralized ownership?

Since FVM is not currently supported by Safe, you will need to first deploy Safe contracts on the FVM network and then request network support by opening a Pull Request in the safe-deployments repository. While the PR is being approved, you can also set up your own Safe infrastructure to run the service either locally or in production.
Hope it helps! Best, Louis
